# Windows forms click and drag impeded by labels

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form. I can move this form when it is running by clicking on it and dragging the window somewhere.

I add labels to this form, clicking on the label and dragging does not move the window.

How do I make it so that it does?

Comment: Draw the text in the form's OnPaint override and delete the labels.

Comment: That would work, but it is not doable for what I am working on. I'm looking for some way that allows me to keep the labels.

Comment: If you want help, you would have to explain why it's not doable.

Comment: You're being a little sharp... I think my explanation was clear. If you want to move a windows form by clicking and dragging, and the spot where you clicked had a label, the window will not move.

Comment: I'm looking for the explanation why the labels are so important.

Comment: For the project I'm working on there is already a good amount of code that expects these labels to exist, and I assume there should be some solution that allows me to keep the labels by passing windows messages to the parent window to make the window think it should be dragging when I click on the label.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't replace the labels with a paint method, try adding an event handler for each label in the form's constructor that calls your form's MouseMove method (which I assume you have code that moves the form):

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  foreach (Label l in this.Controls.OfType<Label>()) {
    l.MouseMove += (sender, e) => { Form1_MouseMove(l, e); };
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this along with using PostMessage and Spy++ to replicate the messages that occur when a click and drag happens, Haven't been able to get it to work. I ended up going with a half measure of your idea, setting all the labels Visible = false (which doesn't change the layout of my form and allows the labels to keep their styling and other settings), then get all the styling info from the labels to draw them in the OnPaint.

Comment: @prw56 You would have to show the code you have for moving the form in your question.  No need for a PostMessage or setting things to invisible, etc.